# Halite/Doctrine vs MySQL AES_ENCRYPT: security/performance

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption, doctrine

I have a web application (Symfony 4) that needs to be HIPAA compliant which (among other things) means I need to encrypt data.  Originally I was just going to encrypt data in PHP via Halite and save it in the database, however there are some fields (last name, first name, phone number) I can't encrypt because they will be used for a search field and therefore I need (?) MySQL to be able to use where clauses.

For this reason I was going to use `AES_ENCRYPT` and set the MySQL connection to go over ssh through a local port forwarded tunnel so that the connection would be secure and no one would be able to get the passphrase.

I keep seeing articles though that `AES_ENCRYPT` is a bad idea and that the stuff should just be secured in PHP.  If I do that, I would need to pull ALL the records down, decrypt them, then have PHP search then - surely not as fast as MySQL could do it (?). This table could have thousands of entries.

Are there any suggestions for this?  Am I overthinking it? What risks would there be in doing it via MySQL if I did connections through ssh?

There is so many suggestions on the internet it's hard to know whats right =/  Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: When you do a lookup on these fields, will you be using a `LIKE` query, or will the values match perfectly?  E.g. if you're looking up "John" for the lastname, values like "Johnson" will be ignored.  If the latter, it **is** possible using an HMAC and symmetric encryption to do an efficient lookup.

Comment: Right now it is a LIKE but it could be changed to use exact matching if the security/performance was worth it

Comment: For the sake of asking - if I wanted to do a LIKE, what options would you think I have?  I thought maybe I could pull just the search fields and the PK ID down and store it in a cache and then have the search use that all through code - the cache would just be in memory on the web server.  Would that be secure?  Is there any other options?

Comment: Realistically speaking there isn't really any way to do this that provides a decent security/performance balance.  It's either heavily performance orientated or it's security orientated.  No middleground.

Comment: Ok - last question/idea I have on this then I'll leave you alone :)  What about if I put just say the first letter of the last name in a separate hash and then used that so I could see say "all last names beginning with 'R'" (I have a table I spit out records to which they can view without a search).  Do you think that would be secure?

Comment: Consider that this additional hash field would have the same value for all fields that start with R. Which means that the set of possible hash values for that field would only have 26 values. Not that hard to figure out which belongs to each letter ;)

Comment: I know they would be able to group last names together at that point, but would they know what letter that hmac stood for?  Also if they figured that out - at that point they would only know the first letter of the last name, could they somehow use that to gain access to the real encrypted last name?

Comment: If you need searchable encryption, check out [CipherSweet](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet/) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're happy to use **exact** lookups, you can implement a lookup on an encrypted field at no performance cost.  You should definitely implement the encryption logic in your PHP code.

If you currently have your table, say:

```
(id, first_name, last_name, email)
```

We first add additional columns for the fields you want encrypted, so our table becomes

```
(id, first_name, first_name_lu, last_name, last_name_lu, email)
```

When we update or insert a row, we do 2 things:

- Using the first symmetric key, we encrypt the required fields.  This result goes in the original column.
- Using the second symmetric key, we HMAC the required field.  This result goes in the `*_lu` column.

When we want to perform a lookup, we:

- Using the second symmetric key, HMAC the search query and then lookup the `*_lu` column based on the result.
- If we find a match, then the encrypted value in the original column is the value we searched for.

You might wonder why the HMAC is necessary at all, why can't we just re-encrypt and compare?  We could do that, but it would also mean that we have to use ECB mode to encrypt, which is a large security vulnerability.  GCM or CBC should be used instead.  This is what makes the HMAC necessary.

Comment: This is an EXCELLENT idea and one I had not previously considered. I think this would provide the best security option, however I still would like a comment on how you think this would compare security-wise vs AES_ENCRYPT() - do you think it would be worth the effort?

Comment: Yes.  You should always avoid encryption logic at the database level.  If your database server is compromised (which is the reason we do this, to keep the data safe if this happens) then any new SQL queries coming in will be visible to the attacker since they control that end of the connection.  If you do it in your application logic (PHP) then the data will already be encrypted before it reaches the database server and the attacker is none the wiser.

Comment: Thank you for the reasoning.  One last question if I may - I read here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php that comparing hmac strings in PHP could lead to a timing attack and one suggestion was to md5 the hashes to prevent that.  Do you know if I would need to do that in MySQL?  Sorry, I know this gets a little off topic

Comment: You shouldn't be doing **any** logic in MySQL.  The only interaction with MySQL should be normal `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`SELECT` style stuff, no cryptographic primitives.  Yep, one way is to MD5 hash first, but a better way is to use a timing safe comparison function.  PHP has [`hash_equals`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) for this.

Comment: right, your suggestion meant to HMAC the value in PHP, send it to MySQL and do the HMAC compare there (against th *_lu field) in the WHERE clause, correct?  Hence why I asked about comparing the hashes (the WHERE clause) in MySQL.

Comment: Ahhhh I see, I misunderstood.  In this case, yes, that is probably the best way to do a timing safe comparison.  Prefer SHA-2 based hashing functions over MD5, however.

Comment: Circling back to this (as I'm FINALLY to the point where I can implement it in my code), just wondering for the sake of asking - would there be any security benefit to storing the fields in something like Argon2 vs HMAC?

Comment: The security comes from the fact that the HMAC is keyed. While this is technically possible with Argon2, it's important to remember that Argon2 is *designed* to be a password hash - which means it is also designed to be very slow. Not ideal for fast table lookups.  Might also be beneficial for your understanding to realize that an HMAC and Argon2 aren't really comparable.  An HMAC is a keyed hash, what that hash is is irrelevant.  Argon2 is a password hashing algorithm.  They aren't they same thing.